# Can't use ?? in blade template, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I wrote this code
`<p>{{ $name or 'hello' }}</p>`,
but it return just 1. I read, that it's syntax used in Laravel 5.7, not higher and change my code to this
`<p>{{ $name ?? 'hello' }}</p>`.
But this code return nothing. Help me, please.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: version php 8.0

Comment: Please post your controller method that return this view

Comment: ``public function show()
    {
        return view('test.show', ['name' => '', 'age' => '36', 'salary' => '500']);
    }``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary operator instead

```
<p>{{ $name ?: 'hello' }}</p>
```

`??` is **null** coalescing operator and in your case `$name` is not null but empty string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary